# Html5 video source from ashx handler

Tags: asp.net, html, video, ashx

I have my video data stored in database and want to play it in my page. I make custom handler(FileHandler.ashx) like this

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int id;
            if (context.Request.QueryString["FileId"] == null || !Int32.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["FileId"], out id))
                return;
            var file = lnxFile.Get(id);
            string fileName = file.Name + file.Extension;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(file.Data);
            context.Response.End();
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
```

And used html5's video tag like this

```
<video id="jwplayer_placeholder" width="320" height="240" controls> 
    <source src="<%= "/CMS/Common/FileHandler.ashx?FileId=" + id %>" type="video/mp4">  
</video>
```

But it doesn't play anything. Can anyone explain me the reason?

Comment: any reason why you didn't accept Aristos's answer?

Answer (score 3):

The main error is that you do not have set the `ContentType` [for the video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video) and you left the browser to decide what it is. Set it as:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "video/mpeg";
```

Also the `"Content-Disposition"` is used for download file, remove that also

The clear have no meaning here, remove it

```
context.Response.Clear();
```

and also set `Buffer=off` because you need to direct send it to the browser.

This sequence have no meaning, keep only the `Flush.`

```
   context.Response.End();
    context.Response.Flush();
```

So the final code will be as:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    int id;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["FileId"] == null || !Int32.TryParse(context.Request.QueryString["FileId"], out id))
        return;
    var file = lnxFile.Get(id);

    context.Response.Buffer = false;
    context.Response.ContentType = "video/mpeg";    
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(file.Data);    
    context.Response.Flush();
}
```